# How to run a php file after writing it and saving in vi editor

Tags: command-line, php, php-cli

I have written a PHP code using vi editor and saved it as `Test.php`. What is the command to run the file in terminal?

Comment: ~/root/adserver/adson/Test.php

Answer (score 2):

You can install PHP-cli :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Then in terminal :

```
php /path-to-Test.php
```

suppose you save your Test.php in your Desktop then the command would be

```
php ~/Desktop/Test.php
```

Or you can

```
cd ~/Desktop
php ./Test.php
```

---

EDIT: based to your comment above: command becomes

```
php  ~/root/adserver/adson/Test.php
```

Comment: what is to be written in php.path-to-Test.php

Comment: where do you save your Test.php?

Comment: You mean root/the directory/filename

Comment: In which folder you have the script?

Comment: adserver folder

Comment: give me the fullpath please

Answer (score 1):

You can also put this at the first line of your PHP script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

This tells your shell that this file should be run with php. After this, if you make your script executable, e.g. with

```
chmod +x Test.php
```

Then you can run it as it were a binary executable:

```
./Test.php
```

or with the full path:

```
./~/root/adserver/adson/Test.php
```

**Note:** Of course you still need to have *php5-cli* installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vim to edit your file you can even execute it within the editor with the command:

```
:!php %
```

The `!` indicates to vim that you want to call an external function, `php` is the external function to execute and `%` referes to your current file (which is the one you want to pass to `php` as an argument).

And as vim is an amazing tool you can even improve your productivity with a mapping. To do so you can add the following line to your `.vimrc`:

```
map <C-e> <Esc> :w<CR> :!php %<CR>
```

This way while you are editing when you will press <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> your file will be saved and then the external call to `php` will be done.

The details of the mapping are the following:

- `<Esc>` makes you leave insert mode if you are still editing to enable normal mode.
- `:w<CR>` calls the `write` function to save your changes.
- The last part is the command I gave you at the beginning of my answer.

Of course to work this method needs that you install php-cli as suggested by @Maythux in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's going to speed up my php coding enormously!